# Numpy: np.sum with negative axis

Tags: numpy

I wonder what does "*If axis is negative it counts from the last to the first axis.*" mean in the [[docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), I've test these:

```
>>> t
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> np.sum(t, axis=1)
array([3, 7])
>>> np.sum(t, axis=0)
array([4, 6])
>>> np.sum(t, axis=-2)
array([4, 6])
```

Still confused, I need some easily understood explanation.

Comment: count from the last means that axis `-1` is equal to axis 1 (the last positive axis) and `-2` to 0 ( one before last which in this case is also the first once because we only have two axises).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First look at list indexing on a length-2 list:

```
>>> L = ['one', 'two']
>>> L[-1]  # last element
'two'
>>> L[-2]  # second-to-last element
'one'
>>> L[-3]  # out of bounds - only two elements in this list
# IndexError: list index out of range
```

The `axis` argument is analogous, except it's specifying the *dimension* of the ndarray.  It will be easier to see if using a non-square array:

```
>>> t = np.arange(1,11).reshape(2,5)
>>> t
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
>>> t.ndim  # two-dimensional array
2
>>> t.shape  # a tuple of length t.ndim
(2, 5)
```

So let's look at the various ways to call sum:

```
>>> t.sum()  # all elements
55
>>> t.sum(axis=0)  # sum over 0th axis i.e. columns
array([ 7,  9, 11, 13, 15])
>>> t.sum(axis=1)  # sum over 1st axis i.e. rows
array([15, 40])
>>> t.sum(axis=-2)  # sum over -2th axis i.e. columns again (-2 % ndim == 0)
array([ 7,  9, 11, 13, 15])
```

Trying `t.sum(axis=-3)` will be an error, because you only have 2 dimensions in this array.  You could use it on a 3d array, though.

Comment: May I ask why it's designed like this?

Comment: If you have many axes, it may be more convenient to count backwards from the end.

Comment: Sometimes you want to index the last axis, irrespective of the number of dimensions of the input.

Comment: It's more convenient to write `t.sum(axis=-1)` than it is to write the equivalent `t.sum(axis=t.ndim-1)`