# What does the parameter -1 means in the sum method of the NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, data-manipulation

Consider the following code:

```
X = rand.rand(10, 2)
differences = X[:, np.newaxis, :] - X[np.newaxis, :, :]
differences = X[:, np.newaxis, :] - X[np.newaxis, :, :]
sq_differences = differences ** 2
dist_sq = sq_differences.sum(-1)
```

In this code, we're calculating the squared distance between the points in the cartesian plane (points are stored in the array X). Please explain the last step in this code, especially that -1 parameter in the sum method.

Comment: Please update the question to show the research you’ve already done to answer this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy: np.sum with negative axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079622/numpy-np-sum-with-negative-axis)

Comment: The question already has answered. Check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079622/numpy-np-sum-with-negative-axis

Comment: The use of `-1` to mean last element or last dimension is quite common in python.

Answer (score 1):

When Numpy.sum() is used to sum a multi dimenstional array it allows you to specify a dimension. For example dimension = 0 works along the column while dimemen =1 works along the row.

This is explained better here [Numpy.sum](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-sum-in-python/amp/)

Now why -1 is used took a little more digging but is a very simple and sensible answer when you find it.

When you pass dimensions as -1 it means to pick the **last** dimension in the array. Such that in a 2D array this would be column